# Creating Database view at startup - JPA

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am using ddl-auto: create-drop to create the schema for my application at startup All was running fine until I needed to create several views. I want to be able to create my database views also at startup

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "my_view")
@Subselect( "my query here" )
Public class MyView {
```

The view is not getting auto generated.

```
 Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'db.my_view' doesn't exist
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor74.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2490)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor125.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy196.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
```

Environment: Mysql, Spring boot, hibernate

Comment: What is the value of `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` in your Hibernate XML file?

Comment: I am using spring boot, I do not have a hibernate XML file. I guess spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto is doing the trick. PS: tables are getting created all fine just the views are not created

Comment: I don't know for certain that Hibernate will create views.  It is possible to map an entity to a view, but not sure about view creation.

Comment: I believe you are right, but I couldn't figure it out in documentation anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flyway to initialize your views.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup

If you went that route, you would probably want to fully use Flyway for your schema instead of using `create-drop`, by switching `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `validate` or `none`.